# opposite of .add method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to subtract from my list. The list is a list of integers, to add to it I wrote the code below, but to subtract from the list I do not know how to do

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Data extends ChangeNotifier {

  int numberOfItems;

  Data({this.numberOfItems});

  List<Data> individualList = [];

  void addIndividual(int newNumber){
    final individualItem = Data(numberOfItems: newNumber);
    individualList.add(individualItem);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

```
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).removeIndividual(numberOfItems);},
                        child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, color: Colors.grey[700], size: 20.0,)),),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 0,
                    child: Text('${Provider.of<Data>(context).individualList.length + 1}',
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Suggest u read this:https://bezkoder.com/dart-list/#Remove_items_from_List_in_DartFlutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void removeIndividual(numberOfItems){
   individualList.remove(individualList.firstWhere((item) => item.numberOfItems == numberofItems);); 
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Edit: Please note, numberOfItems must be unique for every Data object that is created and added to the individualList. Otherwise on removing, you might end up removing some other instance of data object instead of what you desire.
Voila!

Comment: I figured that that's what I should do too, but for some reason when I call the method as                           Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).removeIndividual(numberOfItems); it doesn't work.

Comment: I added in numberOfItems as an int above my build method in my stateless widget by the way

Comment: add the code you wrote to try to remove item in the question so we can see what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I meant the function, your UI part is okay. The removeIndividual function that you are running. Is it the one I gave as an answer?

Comment: I made a change to the answer. Try and let me know!

Comment: Yeah that's the one I tried: void removeIndividual(item){
    individualList.remove(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

Comment: Your most recent edit worked! Thank you so so much, I was really struggling there!

Comment: Glad to help! I'm adding more information in the answer caus it's not foolproof. Must read it.